# How can I use bitwise OR on an enum and an int?

Tags: c#, enums, binary-operators, enum-flags

I have a flag `Enum` called `Role` and an extension method called `AddRole`, that takes a Role enum and an int that works like a flag and only contains ones and zeros, where each 1 represents a role that a person has. I want the method to add the role to the int, so that `AddRole(Role.Grandmother, 1000)` returns **1100** for instance.

```
[Flags]
public enum Role
    {
        Mother = 1,
        Daughter = 2,
        Grandmother = 4,
        Sister = 8,

    }
```

I tried doing this:

```
public static int AddRole(this Role newRole, int currentRoles)
        {
            return (int)((Role)currentRoles | newRole);
        }
```

but this just returns 1004. Does anyone know the right way to do this? 
(I have no way of avoiding the "binary ish" int representation, as this is the way the entity is stored in the (very old and untouchable) database)

Comment: You are confusing decimal and binary representation: a decimal 4 is 100 binary, 1000 decimal (as you call your method) is binary 1111101000....and decimal 1000 ORed with 4 (grandmother) is of course 1004. You probably meant `AddRole(Role.Grandmother, 8)` (because decimal 8 is binary 1000). And you may want to consider giving `Role` the `[Flags]` attribute.

Comment: You should pass `8` or `0b1000 ` as a second parameter instead of `1000`

Comment: The only reasons to encode multiple bools as bits is lack of memory, which is uncommon where C# is used. Make the enum a proper class with bools, use proper logical expressions to combine them. For a larger project you'll end up holding the enum as data in a class anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the actual issue you have is how to interprete a decimal value (like `1000`) as a binary representation.

You can do this by converting it to a string and then let [Convert.ToInt32()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_System_Int32_) overload that takes a *base* argument parse it again as a binary value:

```
int i = 1000;
int b = Convert.ToInt32(i.ToString(), 2); // interprete the string as a binary value
// b = 8
```

Comment: I did not know this, it is neat.